# if current url contains something do something

Tags: javascript

Original idea is to set certain radio button as checked based on current url.
For some reason, my if statement doesn't work. Link URL that leads to the page looks like this

```
domain.com/subdir/pagename#showteal
```

and my code is

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("showblack") > -1) {
   alert('black');
}
 if(window.location.href.indexOf("showteal") > -1) {
   alert('teal');
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use `window.location.hash`, but what you wrote should work. And if the hash changes while on the page, the code is not going to magically run, it will only run when the page is loaded.

Comment: works for me, do you get any console errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to use GET syntax to do so, since the hash is used to anchor the page into the elements id.

So, with GET, your link would looks like `domain.com/subdir/pagename?show=teal`

This function should do the trick:

```
function get(name){
    if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search))
        return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
}
```

and it's use get simple like `var show = get("show");`

I hope it works for ya.

Answer (score 0):

Since your are looking for a string in the hash, using jQuery :

```
$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {
      if(window.location.hash.indexOf("showblack") > -1) {
       alert('black');
    }
     if(window.location.hash.indexOf("showteal") > -1) {
       alert('teal');
    }
 });
```

Comment: Hopefully OP has jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try:

window.location.hash.indexOf("showteal")